# remove blank space under static block categories in magento site

Tags: magento

in home page, you can see "special categories " with 6 red images.

below those images some empty space is displaying.

I want to delete those empty space.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS add the following, adjusting the margin to taste.

```
 .wrapper-category .home_cat {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```